# Django 1.8 won't start

Tags: django, django-1.8

After migrating to `Django 1.8` my app doesn't start. Error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./manage.py", line 20, in
<module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "***/.virtualenvs/vtslive/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "***/.virtualenvs/vtslive/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
line 312, in execute
    django.setup()   File "***/.virtualenvs/vtslive/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py",
line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "***/.virtualenvs/vtslive/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
line 78, in populate
    raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant") RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

I can't find solution for that issue :/

Comment: Please provide the INSTALLED_APPS tuple that you have declared in your settings.py file.

Comment: This error is a real pain to debug. What I have had to do in the past is comment out the exception handlers in `django/apps/registry.py` that are swallowing the **actual** exception that is causing the error. This error message is perhaps the *least* useful I've ever encountered in Django.

Comment: If you're lucky, it's could be because you've accidentally added a module to your `INSTALLED_APPS` twice, but more likely it's a missing dependency.

Comment: The exception message tells exactly what the problem is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing). Duplicate apps raise a different error message. How is your Celery set up to run? That would probably be the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem. I use `celery` and to make it work in `Django 1.7` I had to add this line to `celery.py`

```
django.setup()
```

After removing it, both `celery` and my app started to work :)

@Brandon you're 100% right - this exception tells nothing ;)

Comment: I had this same scenario, and after I removed this from `celery.py`, Celery stopped working, but I got the real error: I had a duplicated app in `INSTALLED_APPS`